# Unable to use components of different layout in android main activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

In my activity I am displaying splash(splash.xml) screen for 5 sec and then I am changing content view to my actual layout of main activity(activity_main). But when I am trying to use the components in the my main activity layout(activity_main) I am getting null pointer exception.

Main Activity is

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
ProgressBar progressBar2;
EditText userName,password;
static String url;
JSONObject reader;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    new CountDownTimer(5000,1000){
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){}

        @Override
        public void onFinish(){
            //set the new Content of your activity
            MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }
    }.start();
    progressBar2=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    userName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userName);
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
}
}
```

when I use any of this components I am getting null pointer exception.

My splash Screen layout file splash.xml

```
            <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_web">
            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="111dp"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

and the main layout(activity_main.xml is)

```
            <LinearLayout 

            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:hint="Password"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Remember me"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:checked="false"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Login"
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:onClick="login"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Signup"
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:onClick="signUp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center">
            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar2"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your

```
    @Override
    public void onFinish(){
        //set the new Content of your activity
        MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
```

will be executed after 5 seconds.

Set your layout

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

before `progressBar2=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);`